# I'm unable to persist a an object, using doctrine, that has a composite primary key that includes a foreign key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, persist

I created an ER model for my project and implemented it in php and added the following maaping information:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Competition:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
        location:
        date:
            type: datetime
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    oneToMany:
        runs:
            targetEntity: Run
            mappedBy: comp
            cascade: [persist]
```

,

```
AppBundle\Entity\Run:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
        comp:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        name:
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
        comp:
            targetEntity: Competition
            inversedBy: runs
```

and

```
AppBundle\Entity\Participate:
    type: entity
    id:
        athlete:
            associationKey: true
        run:
            associationKey: true
        comp:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        number:
            type: integer
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
        athlete:
            targetEntity: Athlete
            cascade: [persist]
        run:
            targetEntity: Run
            cascade: [persist]
        comp:
            targetEntity: Run
            cascade: [persist]
```

*EDIT: Run should be a weak Entity, so I think I need the 2 relations to Run. First for the Run itself and second for the Competition, the Run belongs to.*

Working with Competition and Run works like a charm, I can persist and fetch them, but as soon as I try to persist an object of Participate, i get the following error:

> Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not supported. You should split the parameter into the explicit fields and bind them separately.

I use the following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($participate);
$em->flush();
```

I don't know what I should do to resolve this problem.

Thanks

EDIT2:

I just understood, that theoretically, I don't need the relation `comp` in `Participate` as it is already in `Run` and the `Run`objects are unique. But if I want to update my database accordingly, Doctrine gives me the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE Participate DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_8B9E3EEF4D0D3BCB;
DROP INDEX IDX_8B9E3EEF4D0D3BCB ON Participate;
ALTER TABLE Participate DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE Participate DROP comp_id;
ALTER TABLE Participate ADD PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id, run_id);
```

Which would remove the foreign key to `Competition` in `Participate`. But `run_id` is not defined as unique, because it should be a weak key.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because 2 manyToOne relations have the same entity as targetEntity

```
AppBundle\Entity\Participate
  manyToOne:
    run: targetEntity: Run
    comp: targetEntity: Run
```

Comp should have the targrtEntity "Competition".

Comment: But this would make a relation between Participate and Competition. Participate should, however, only be in relation with Run, which has a composite PK

Comment: So why don't you just create an intermediary entity to avoid using it twice?

Comment: I don't really understand. I added some Information in the Question.